# Calculate the limit: $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {4(n+3)!-n!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate the limit:
$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {4(n+3)!-n!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)}$
My attempt: $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {4(n+3)!-n!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)} = \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {4(n+2)!(n+3)-n(n-1)!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)} = \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {n(\frac{4}{n}(n+2)!(n+3)-(n-1)!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)} = \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {\frac{4}{n}(n+2)!(n+3)-(n-1)!}{(n+2)!-(n-1)!} $
And here I am stuck.
I could do this: $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac {(4 +\frac{12}{n})(n+2)!-(n-1)!}{(n+2)!-(n-1)!}$But it doesn't get my anywhere. I was able to guess the right answer(4), but how to get to it in a proper calculation way?

Comment: How about divide the numerator and the denominator by $(n-1)!$ first?

Comment: Or (quicker) divide both numerator and denominator by $(n+2)!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\frac {4(n+3)!-n!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)}
=&
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\frac {(n+3)!\left[{4}-\frac{n!}{(n+4)!}\right]}
{n(n+2)!\left[1-\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+2)!}\right]}
\\
=&
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\frac {(n+3)!\left[4-\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}\right]}{n(n+2)!\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\right]}
\\
=&
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\frac{(n+3)}{n}
\frac {\left[4-\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}\right]}{\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\right]}
\\
=&
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)
\frac {\left[4-\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}\right]}{\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\right]}
\\
=&
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdot
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }
\frac {\left[ 4-\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}\right]}{\left[1-\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\right]}
\\
=&
\left(1+\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdot
\frac {\left[ 4-\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}\right]}{\left[1-\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)n}\right]}
\\
=&
\left(1+0\right)\cdot
\frac {\left[ 4-0\right]}{\left[1-0\right]}=4
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$ \frac {4(n+3)!-n!}{n((n+2)!-(n-1)!)}\sim 
\frac {4(n+3)!}{n((n+2)!)}=  \frac {4(n+3)}{n}\to 4$$

Answer (score 1):

It is:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n!(4(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-1}{n!(n(n+1)(n+2)-1)}=\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3\left[4\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n^3}\right]}{n^3\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n^3}\right]}=\frac{4(1+0)(1+0)(1+0)-0}{(1+0)(1+0)-0}=4.$$

Comment: Have a question about factoring out from the denumerator n!. Are you sure that $n!*(1) = (n-1)!$ ?

Comment: Sure, if you take $(n-1)!$ out of brackets and multiply by $n$, it becomes $n!$.

Comment: Shouldn't in the denumerator be $n!(n(n+1)(n+2)-\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Nope, it is: $n[(n-1)!\{n(n+1)(n+2)-1\}]=n(n-1)!\{n(n+1)(n+2)-1\}=n!\{n(n+1)(n+2)-1\}.$

Comment: One last thing. Could you please add and explain the last simplification step? $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n!(4(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-1}{n!(n(n+1)(n+2)-1)} = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{4(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)-1}{n(n+1)(n+2)-1} $$ How do you simplify next? Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing I don't understand now is where $n^3$ comes from (I guess, you multiplied and divided the fraction by it). However, how did -1 become $-\frac{1}{n^3}$ ?

Comment: I took the largest degree of $n$ (i.e. $n^3$) out of brackets (you can also divide by $n^3$).

Answer (score 1):

You can collect $(n-1)!$ in the numerator and in the denominator, giving
$$
\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)!}\frac{4(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n-n}{n\bigl((n+2)(n+1)n-1\bigr)}=
\frac{4n^4+f(n)}{n^4+g(n)}=
\frac{4+\dfrac{f(n)}{n^4}}{1+\dfrac{g(n)}{n^4}}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of degree less than $4$. Now use that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}{n^4}=0
$$
There is no need to write down $f$ and $g$ explicitly.